# Gridview randomly failing to update properly on first load, remains incorrect until it's destroyed

Tags: android, gridview, android-imageview

I have a 2x27 gridview that's holding white imageviews.  I then apply a colorfilter to the imageviews, and every cycle invalidate them.  The end result is some animated colors moving around the gridview.

I'm having problems with the gridview randomly showing a white square, instead of the black I initalize everything to.  Then, as the colors change every imageview updates, except for the ones that failed to load properly the first time.  They always remain white.

Sometimes this doesn't happen. Sometimes it's 1 square, sometimes it's 4 squares.

If I rotate my screen, the stuck white ones go away and everything works. They never come back no matter how many times I rotate/leave the activity and return.

This is me updating the colorfilters.  I've checked in here that every grid is getting updated, nothing remains white.

```
 public void updateColors() {

    Runnable runnable1 = new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {

              int r = 0;
              int g = 0;
              int b = 0;
              int y = 0;

            while(keepRunning == true){

                y = 0;

                for(int x=0;x<Consts.VIEWCOUNT;x++){                
                          g = Buffers.offLineBuffer_[y++];            
                          r = Buffers.offLineBuffer_[y++];
                          b = Buffers.offLineBuffer_[y++];

                          Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[x]);             
                          myIcon.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.rgb(r, g, b),PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));                              
                 }

              try {             
                Thread.sleep(55);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }

              handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                  gridView.invalidateViews();

                }
              });
            }
          }
        };
        new Thread(runnable1).start();
```

}

This is my adapter

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
         imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(33, 33));            

    } else {
     imageView = (ImageView) convertView;

    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);    
    return imageView;
}
```

mThumbsID is just a list of ID's to drawables like below (I shortened it)

```
public static Integer[] mThumbIdsTemp = {
        R.drawable.image1,
        R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3,
        R.drawable.image4,
}
```

It just started doing this one day, I haven't been able to track it back to what is causing it, or why it's only ever on the first time it's loaded, but will remain until it's destroyed via rotating the screen.

I've lost over a day trying to track this down, and I'm lost as to what might be causing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: For the question about the colors changing - they are hard coded all to black in this example. The array I loop through is all black.  I took out the code that changes the colors to stuff other than black because it happens without it.  White squares, even though it's black.

Comment: Glad it started to work; i removed my answer because it contained some missinfo I learned after [reading here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html) about constant state pooling for drawables, and didn't want to confuse anyone else who comes along.

Comment: Hmm I'll have to read through that more carefully later tonight.  Do you think it's not a sync lock issue then, and something more about the constant state?

Comment: Nah, the pooled constant state undermined the points I made about the drawables being potentially distinct instances.  It may not matter.